# Count row on table2 based on table1 with prepared statement

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

**clients_db**

```
| clnt_id | clnt_sid | usr_sid | clnt_name |
|    1    | 12345678 |  10001  |   Peter   |
|    2    | 87654321 |  10001  |   Mikey   |
```

**aircon_client_db**

```
|  ac_id  | clnt_sid |
|    1    | 12345678 |
|    2    | 12345678 |
|    3    | 12345678 |
|    4    | 87654321 |
|    5    | 87654321 |
```

This is query:

```
select *,count(air.ac_id) as nAC
from clients_db clnt 
left join aircon_client_db air on air.clnt_sid=clnt.clnt_sid
where clnt.usr_sid=? 
group by clnt.clnt_sid
order by clnt.clnt_name asc
```

From the code above. I expect the result `clnt_id[1]=3` and `clnt_id[2]=2`. But the result returns `0` for all. Where should I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to select the `count(air.ac_id)`.

Also replace `clnt.usr_sid=?` with `clnt.clnt_id=?` if you're going to expect a result like `clnt_id[1]=3`.

```
select count(air.ac_id) as nAC
from clients_db clnt 
left join aircon_client_db air on air.clnt_sid=clnt.clnt_sid
where clnt.clnt_id=?
group by clnt.clnt_sid
order by clnt.clnt_name asc
```

Are you missing `clnt_name` as column in your question?

Comment: Yeah I forgot that column, fixed now! But still not working. It's not count ;(

Comment: Please see this example based on yours https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gy4GHUUbZQRqHdKfDEJaVR/0, the query I posted is working as expected.

Comment: But when I changed the cause `where clnt.usr_sid=10001` ...error!

Comment: You can only order by columns appearing in the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregates. Is the order by really useful for you?

Comment: The `order by ` is not really matter here. But once I remove it. Nothing change  ;(

Comment: If you remove the `order by clnt.clnt_name asc` or use `order by clnt.clnt_sid asc` it works. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gy4GHUUbZQRqHdKfDEJaVR/1

Comment: I tried:
`select count(air.ac_id) as nAC
from clients_db clnt 
left join aircon_client_db air on air.clnt_sid=clnt.clnt_sid
where clnt.usr_sid='10001'
group by air.clnt_sid
` ...and it WORKS!!! But not to my code, figuring out why...

Comment: Good to know, if you need any help edit your answer with your code.

Comment: Is it has something to do with data type of the column?

Comment: I tried changing it to varchar and it still works on test https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gy4GHUUbZQRqHdKfDEJaVR/2

Comment: Um... let me check with my DB and other code if there's any conflicts.

Comment: When I select more than 1 column. It errors : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gy4GHUUbZQRqHdKfDEJaVR/0

Comment: Please click 'Update' on top left of **db-fiddle**, I see the old script on your link!

Comment: Just edit GROUP BY as follow `group by air.clnt_sid, clnt.clnt_sid`

Comment: The fiddle from you is working. But still unable to print the `count` from each `clnt_sid`. Don't know why...

Comment: What language are you using? Can I see the code? Maybe it's something wrong in fetching the result from the working query.

Comment: I think you're calling a variable `$nAC` here `number_format($nAC)` which isn't set. Maybe `$row['nAC']`?

Comment: How stupid am I. You're right man!!! :( Case closed!!! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `*` but explicit column name  or in this case you could also use `clnt.*` (you don't need  the value for the left joined  table but only the count(*)

```
select clnt.clnt_id, clnt.clnt_sid  ,count(air.ac_id) as nAC
from clients_db clnt 
left join aircon_client_db air on trim(air.clnt_sid)=trim(clnt.clnt_sid)
AND  trim(clnt.user_sid)= '10001'
group by clnt.clnt_sid
order by clnt.clnt_name asc
```

Comment: answer  already updated .. add .table name alias  clnt.clnt_sid

Comment: Seems like I have to prefixed all column with `clnt` or I have an error : `'Column 'clnt_sid' in field list is ambiguous'`

Comment: By the way, after I put `clnt` in front. It still not count as expected. :(

Comment: which data type are the columns  clnt_sid in both tables

Comment: could be your   input paramter don't match  you columns value for join don't match

Comment: `clnt_sid` is varchar

Comment: answer updated  .. adding trim for remove hiiden char  and fixed  value for check you sample   ..

Comment: `AND trim()` also include other `clnt_sid` from the table too :(

Comment: explain better  ..  you comment is not clear  .. there are  3 trim ... (seems that begin to work  at least)

Comment: Yeah, `user_sid` is the owner of each `clnt_id`. So each `user_sid` can have more than 1 `clnt_sid` as well. 

I want to loop count how many of `ac_id` each `clnt_sid` has under the same `user_sid`.

Comment: then if you filter for user_id  you should obatin two row one with count 3 and one with count 2

Comment: Yes, I want something just like that.

Comment: The actual result is all zero. Even I cleared all the column but count.